# Getting content from custom UITextfields in an UIAlertview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, uialertview

Got the following code:

```
-(void)addGrade {

    UIAlertView *alertview = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Text" message:@"\n \n \n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add", nil];

    // Textfield1

    UITextField *utextfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 50.0, 260.0, 25.0)];

    [utextfield becomeFirstResponder];

    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];

    utextfield.leftView = paddingView;
    utextfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

    utextfield.placeholder = @"Subject";
    [utextfield setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    utextfield.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    [alertview addSubview:utextfield];


    // Textfield2

    UITextField *ptextfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 85.0, 90.0, 25.0)];

    ptextfield.placeholder = @"Another Subject";
    ptextfield.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    ptextfield.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    [ptextfield setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [alertview addSubview:ptextfield];

    // Textfield3

    UITextField *ctextfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(161.0, 85.0, 27.0, 25.0)];

    ctextfield.placeholder = @"3";
    [ctextfield setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    ctextfield.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    ctextfield.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [alertview addSubview:ctextfield];


    // Label1

    UILabel *telt = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(121.0, 85.0, 40.0, 25.0)];

    telt.text = @"Text";
    telt.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    telt.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [alertview addSubview:telt];

    // Label2

    UILabel *keermee = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(199.0, 85.0, 100.0, 25.0)];

    keermee.text = @"more text";
    keermee.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    keermee.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [alertview addSubview:keermee];

    [alertview show];

}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {


    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if ([title isEqualToString:@"Add"])
    {
        UITextField *field = (UITextField *)[[alertView subviews] lastObject];
        NSLog (@"%@", field.text);

    }




}
```

This code makes 3 Textfields and 2 labels in an UIAlertView.

With `UITextField *field = (UITextField *)[[alertView subviews] lastObject];` I got back "more text" which is true because you are asking about the last object.

Now is my question how to get the content of all the UITextfield not only the label?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (UIView *view in [alertView subviews]){
    if ([view isMemberOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)view;

        NSLog(@"%@", textField.text);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but what should I put in the `// Do your code` to get the content that was put in the textfields? When I try an NSLog I got 3 times the same log back.

Comment: UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)view;

Comment: This method Will be 3 Tines executed if you have 3 textfields.

Comment: I edit the code. When I try that code I got with 1 NSLog() 3 objects back. How to separate these 3 object to 3 UITextFields?

Answer (score 1):

Assign tags and retrieve them with those.

```
myTextField.tag = 100;
```

Then to find it use this function:

```
myTextField = [view subviewWithTag: 100];
```